# SwiftUI [ShareSheet] connection invalidated. Attempt to present which is already presenting

Tags: swiftui, rootviewcontroller, ios-sharesheet

I'm trying to create a share button in my app. App on SwiftUi, Xcode version 13.2.1, iPhone 15.2

**If I use this code:**

```
let url = URL(string: "https://example.com")
let activityController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [url!], applicationActivities: nil)                        
UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController!.present(activityController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

**This is the error:**

> [Presentation] Attempt to present <UIActivityViewController: 0x7feb1600e600> on
> <*TtGC7SwiftUI19UIHostingControllerGVS_15ModifiedContentVS_7AnyViewVS_12RootModifier*_:
> 0x7feb16a05430> (from
> <*TtGC7SwiftUI19UIHostingControllerGVS_15ModifiedContentVS_7AnyViewVS_12RootModifier*_:
> 0x7feb16a05430>) which is already presenting
> <*TtGC7SwiftUI29PresentationHostingControllerVS_7AnyView*:
> 0x7feb05f142e0>.

I understand that it is already presenting, but I don't understand how you can get around it.

**If I use this combination of:**

If I add a **.presentedViewController?** and get this combination, the share button works, but only on iPhone and there are a lot of errors in the console, on iPad the application crashes completely.

```
UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController!.presentedViewController?.present(activityController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Can you tell me how to get around this problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 7):

I was able to solve the problem using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67232269/18064762). Perhaps it will be of use to someone, as it was to me.

By changing one line

```
source.present(activityVC, animated: true)
```

to this

```
source.presentedViewController?.present(activityVC, animated: true)
```

Comment: I run into the same problem, Thanks for sharing your solution!!